# Finding documentation on names returned by dir()

Tags: python

If you run the following code:

```
from flask import Flask 
import unittest 

dir(Flask(__name__).test_client())
```

The following is output to terminal:

[image]

There are a number of names returned that I cannot find documentation on (all of the names that are not surrounded by double underscores).

I have found indirect reference to post [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/#testing) (if you search for 'self.app.post' you'll see it referenced). Note: this link describes using .post with the following keywords: `data` and `follow_redirects`. It does not mention that you can also use the keywords `content_type` and `headers`. Perhaps the only reason that these keyword options are not intuitively obvious to me is because I'm new to this...

Does anyone know where documentation on these names resides? (I can't find it in flask/python/unittest documentation anywhere - perhaps I am looking in the wrong place?)

edit: with the help of the answers, I found [this](http://rallion.bitbucket.org/explorations/flask_tutorial/api/flask.testing.FlaskClient.html#flask.testing.FlaskClient.get) documentation.

Comment: That page clearly describes get and post; it shouldn't be too much of a stretch to work out what put, delete, head and options do, based on that.

Comment: okay, perhaps the only reason I don't intuit what each of these names do is because this I'm new to this, and as I learn more I'll understand them. Thanks.

Comment: To explain a bit more, these are all HTTP verbs.

Comment: @DanielRoseman okay, thanks.

Comment: Well, here are the ones from the list that are HTTP requests: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Comment: @DanielRoseman that page describes post and get, but it leaves out that you can also use the keywords: content_type (string) and headers (list) for the .post method. The only reason I know that these can also be used is because of the tutorial that I'm learning from uses them. Does intuiting these keywords also fit under the 'it'll be obvious when I know more'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check the docstring of the method - comments that developers left when they wrote the code. You can check any object or method you need. For example:

```
Flask.__doc__
unittest.__doc__
dir.__doc__
dir.__doc__.__doc__
```

You can also query

```
Flask(__name__).test_client().post.__doc__
Flask(__name__).test_client().preserve_context.__doc__
```

But you'll notice that not all methods would be documented. For example:

```
Flask(__name__).test_client().open.__doc__
```

For more about this you can also see http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Using help() gives you the same information but formatted, e.g.:

```
help(Flask)
help(unittest)
help(dir)
help(dir.__doc__)
```

Answer (score 2):

For any `Python` Module, Class, Method (all of these in `Python` are `object` indeed), you can view the `doc` by:

```
>>> a_module.__doc__
>>> a_class.__doc__
>>> a_method.__doc__
```

To see more detailed documents, you can use `help` command:

```
>>> help(a_method)
```

Comment: `help()` is not more detailed than `__doc__`. It is the same text, but formatted/rendered.